# Node js (express) No me redirige a mi documento html, me da error cannot GET

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estaba haciendo una práctica de js con html y css, cuando decicidí usar un server con express, para hacerle get y post a las rutas. Aquí os dejo tanto el código como las rutas.

```
const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + './Frontend/index.html'));

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Servidor web escuchando en el puerto ' + port);
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las rutas de mi proyecto.

Comment: Ese es el código entero? Siento que falta importar el módulo; const express = require('express')

Comment: a mi me parece que te hace falta decir cual es el problema que tienes ... Te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
[ask] y 
[mre] y 
[help/on-topic] y 
[help/dont-ask]

Comment: Escribiste la ruta mal. Para comprobarlo cree un directorio llamado PrueaJs, dos subdirectorios: backend y frontend (replicando tu proyecto). Le pedí un `console.log(__dirname + './Frontend/index.html');` y me respondió con `/Pruea Js/backend./Frontend/index.html` en vez de `/Pruea Js/Frontend/index.html`. Mira otra forma de llamar a la carpeta.  [Aquí encontré la forma de hacerlo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350684/how-to-use-dirname-with-a-sibling-directory), en vez de dirname utiliza global. He intentado replicarlo y no lo he conseguido. suerte.

Comment: Hola, si me faltó copiar la constante de require ('express'), y si si lo tenía importado en el código de JavaScript y aún así me daba el error

Comment: @rubenaldown `const express = require ('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/HTML_JAVASCRIPT/Backend./Frontend/index.html'));

app.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Servidor web escuchando en el puerto ' + port);
});`
Me sigue dando error a pesar de poner las rutas